# How should I handle functions and cmdlets that return values of varying types?

Tags: powershell, types, error-handling

Many functions and cmdlets return different types depending on the arguments passed to it. This makes it necessary for me to test the return value. Currently I'm doing this with nested if-then-else statements. Here is an example script I started writing today to validate an IP configuration:

```
$adapters = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
$adapters_type = $adapters.gettype().tostring()
if ($adapters_type -eq "System.Management.ManagementObject") {
    #TODO: configure network adapter.
}
else if ($adapters_type -eq "System.Object[]") {
  #TODO: handle the case of multiple network adapters.
}
else {
  echo "error: unexpected type returned from internal function."
}
```

When I have multiple return variables to test my code becomes deeply nested quickly. Is there a more natural way for handling variables that may be inhabited by one of many types?

Comment: Your example doesn't return multiple types. It returns a collection(object[] array) with mulitple ManagementObjects inside. Do you need to do anything different if more then one object returns? If not, why can't you just run a foreach-loop? That way it handles both 1 or multiple items.

Comment: @Graimer If run on a system with a single network adapter it returns a single object of type `System.Management.ManagementObject`. I'll need to check for that case. Is there a way to avoid runtime errors in this case if I don't make the check?

Comment: If you run it through pipeline instead of saving to $adapters, you should be able to just use foreach-loop(%). ex: `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'" | % { #your code. the current adapter is the object $_ }` :-) I guess I was unclear in my last comment. hope this explained it better

Comment: @Graimer I see. Do I understand correctly that `foreach` work with single objects as if they were an array of size one?

Comment: There may be exceptions that I can't remember at the moment, but yes, foreach usually behaves like that.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to ensure that the result on Get-WmiObject is always an array e.g.:

```
$adapters = @(get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'")
foreach ($adapter in $adapters) {
    #TODO: configure adapter
}
```

Other than that and possibly using a switch statement instead of a bunch of if/else statements, there's no better way to handle differing return types that I can think of.

Comment: Wrapping the result in an @(...) does help in this case. Thanks! I can see myself using this whenever a cmdlet may return a single or multiple results. It appears that powershell flattens nested arrays of a single element such as @(@(1, 2, 3)) down to @(1, 2, 3).

Comment: yes it does. And if you want to keep the array(create an array of arrays), use `@(,@(1,2,3))`. notice the comma before the array values.